# Reorder views in android

Tags: android, screen, row, android-linearlayout

I have three views in a horizontal LinearLayout. One ImageView and two TextView.
Sometimes the first Textview become too large so the second don't appear on screen. I would like to put the second in a new line automatically. is it posible?

Answer (score 0):

Using `LinearLayout` - no.
You can force wordwrapping for `TextView`s instead.